# Clarification on calling CreateProcessAsUser with command line parameters using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I'm somewhat confused about the proper way of calling [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with command line parameters. So without going into details of filling out the rest of its parameters, can someone confirm that this is how it should be done? (In other words, should I put the exe file path as the first command line parameter, or specifying it as `lpApplicationName` is enough?)

```
LPCTSTR pExePath = L"c:\\program files\\sub dir\\program.exe";
LPCTSTR pCmdLine = L"v=\"one two\"";

TCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
StringCchCopy(buff, MAX_PATH, _T("\""));
StringCbCat(buff, MAX_PATH, pExePath);
StringCbCat(buff, MAX_PATH, _T("\" "));
StringCbCat(buff, MAX_PATH, pCmdLine);

CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, pExePath, buff, NULL, NULL, FALSE, dwFlags, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If 2nd param to `CreateProcessAsUser` is `NULL`, then the module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the 3rd param.

If 2nd param to `CreateProcessAsUser` is not `NULL`, then it will be taken as the executable to execute. In this case, the 3rd param can either be

a) `"EXENAME p1 p2"`

or it can be

b) `"p1 p2"`

If you chose a), then the child process will have the following

`argv[0] --> EXENAME`

`argv[1] --> p1`

`argv[2] --> p2`

If you chose b), then the child process will have

`argv[0] --> p1`

`argv[1] --> p2`

Either way, the process to be executed would be `EXENAME` (the 2nd param to `CreateProcessAsUser`). The called process however should be aware of the way command line arguments are going to be coming in.

If you use b), you also have the option of passing 2nd param to `CreateProcessAsUser` as `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks. But don't most Windows processes expect the A scenario? Also shouldn't quotes be like so `"EXENAME" p1 p2`?

Comment: Most `C/C++` programmers would use use a). Also, you need quotes around `PATHANDEXENAME` only if the `PATHANDEXENAME` contains spaces. i.e. "c:\\mypath\\a.exe" would work fine without the extra quotes, but "\"c:\\my path\\a.exe\"" would need it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this insight. Saved me a lot of headaches.