# Launching an elevated process using a windows service

Tags: vb.net, windows, winapi

I'm trying to run a software update from a Windows Service. My service runs under LocalSystem.

I think all works fine up to the `CreateProcessAsUser` line which fails with API error 3 (`ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`).

I'm unsure how to go on debugging my code. I used ProcMon to see if it really can't find the path, but it does, so I think I might have missed something else.

Does anybody see a possible mistake?

I am using `WTSEnumerateSessions` to get the active session. For some reason, its `MachineName` member is empty, but the `SessionID` is *not* 0, so I guess that is still ok.

```
Public Function StartAppInSessionAsAdmin(ByVal uSessionID As String, ByVal uWinstationNameStrPtr As Long, ByVal uAppName As String) As Integer

    'get SessionID token
    Dim hToken&
    Dim bRet As Boolean
    bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(uSessionID, hToken)
    WriteLog "wtsqueryusertoken: " & bRet & ", htoken: " & hToken

    'we need to get the TokenLinked Token
    Dim TLT As TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN
    Dim TLTSize&
    TLTSize = Len(TLT.LinkedToken)

    Dim hLinkedToken&
    Dim iRetSize&
    bRet = GetTokenInformation(hToken, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenLinkedToken, hLinkedToken, TLTSize, iRetSize)
    WriteLog "gettokeninformation: " & bRet & " linkedtoken: " & TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenLinkedToken & " linked2: " & hLinkedToken

    'Use CreateEnvironment Block with the original token to create an environment for the new program with the USER Environment
    Dim lpEB&
    bRet = CreateEnvironmentBlock(lpEB, hToken, False)
    WriteLog "Createenvblock: " & bRet

    If bRet Then

        Dim pi  As PROCESS_INFORMATION
        Dim si As STARTUPINFO
        si.lpDesktop = uWinstationNameStrPtr '  '”Winsta0\default”
        si.cb = Len(si)

        Dim lRet&
        lRet = CreateProcessAsUser( _
        hLinkedToken, _
        "", _
        uAppName, _
        0&, _
        0&, _
        0&, _
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, _
        0&, _
        0&, _
        si, _
        pi)

        'Give user a feedback
        If lRet <> 0 Then
            WriteLog ":-) createprocessasuser succeeded!"
        Else
            WriteLog ":-( failed createprocessasuser! error: " & Err.LastDllError
        End If
    End If

    WriteLog "pstartappinsessions}"

End Function
```

Comment: The Local System account has _a lot_ of control over the system. Is there some reason you have to run the update program in the context of a logged on user? Also, read the documentation about the [lpCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx) parameter. (Specifically the parts about where it will look for the executable, and the part about spaces in the path)

Comment: @theB To my knowledge, I have to run the update program in the context of the logged on user to make it work, but I'm a total beginner at working with accounts. Thank you, I will have a look at the lpCommandLine, but my path does not have spaces.

Comment: According to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001186/clarification-on-calling-createprocessasuser-with-command-line-parameters-using) I have changed uAppName to         uAppName = uAppName & ChrW(160), but it made no difference. Also, when I used uAppName as the second parameter, I got API error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified).

Comment: Edit: Without the white space and the app name as the 2nd param, it works!! :-))) Thank you so much! Can you make your reply the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` strongly suggests that the executable cannot be found. In other words, the problem is with `lpApplicationName` or `lpCommandLine`. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx):

> The `lpApplicationName` parameter can be `NULL`. In that case, the module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the `lpCommandLine` string. If you are using a long file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin; otherwise, the file name is ambiguous. [...] If the file name does not contain an extension, .exe is appended.

If `lpApplicationName` is null, then `lpCommandLine` must start with the program you want to run.  If the path to the program contains a space, then the path must be enclosed in quotes.

If `lpApplicationName` is null, then you can test whether `lpCommandLine` is valid by pasting its value into a command prompt.